# I am trying to scrape a website for my project but I am stuck with an error. Take a look and let me know if anyone have suggestion for this

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
html_text = requests.get('https://www.trustpilot.com/categories/restaurants_bars? 
numberofreviews=0&status=claimed&timeperiod=0').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
restaurants = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'internal___1jK0Z wrapper___26yB4')
for index, restaurant in enumerate(restaurants):
    name = restaurant.find('div', class_ = 'businessTitle___152-c').text
    rating = restaurant.find('div', class_ = 'textRating___3F1NO').text
    with open('{index}.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name)
        f.write(',')
        f.write(rating)
        f.write('\n')

    print('File saved')
```

This is the code throwing an error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 8, in 
name = restaurant.find('div', class_ = 'businessTitle___152-c').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran your code and printed out the relevant bits. The set of classes you are targeting, the `internal___1jK0Z wrapper___26yB4`is not only used for restaurant websites, but also for the about link in the footer of the page. I think that set of classes is used for every link, rather than just the links of restaurant websites.

[image]

Comment: yes Matthew I get the idea from your answer that how to scrape the website to exclude this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an attribute of an object of type `None`, probably one of your queries is returning `None`.

Comment: I can't figure out it, well thank you I am now looking a bit deeper in my code.